# Is it bad approach to make wrappers for public/private routes in react-router v6 like this

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In app I know that user is authenticated when there is token in redux.
When app loads I first fetch that token from server.
I made a wrapper for private and public routes.
I made wrapper for public routes because if user is on login page and reload app once token is fetched I need to make redirect to authenticated page.
What troubles me is this approach ok and does it make performance problems for the future?
Without public route wrapper user is able to access login page when authenticated (which should not).
I am trying to make a clean solution as possible.
This is my routes rendering:

```
return (
    <Routes>
       {routes.map((route, index) => {
        if (route.isProtected) {
          return (
            <Route
              key={index}
              path={route.path}
              element={
                <RequireAuth>            <<<< wrapper
                  <route.component />
                </RequireAuth>
              }
            />
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <Route
              key={index}
              path={route.path}
              element={<Public><route.component /></Public>} <<<< wrapper
            />
          );
        }
      })} 
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
```

Public wrapper

```
function Public({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const {token, tokenChecking} = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth);
  
  if (tokenChecking) {
    return (
        <div>app is loading...</div>
    )
}
  
  if (token) {
    return <Navigate to={state?.from || "/dashboard"}  replace/>;
  }

  return children;
}
```

Private route is more or less reverse

```
function RequireAuth({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) {
  let location = useLocation();

  const {token, tokenChecking} = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth);
  
  if (token) {
    return (
        <div>App is loading ...</div>
    )
}

  if (!token) {
    return <Navigate to={"/login"} state={{ from: location }} />;
  }

  return children;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What troubles me is this approach ok and does it make performance
> problems for the future?

This approach seems reasonable to me and I don't foresee any performance issues with it.

If you want to make the code a bit more DRY then I suggest looking at the `isProtected` flag first and instantiate the wrapper first, then render a single wrapper and component. Remember that React components are PascalCased, so create a `Component` to render into the wrapper.

```
return (
  <Routes>
    {routes.map((route) => {
      const Wrapper = route.isProtected ? RequireAuth : Public;
      const Component = route.component;
      return (
        <Route
          key={route.path}
          path={route.path}
          element={
            <Wrapper> 
              <Component />
            </Wrapper>
          }
        />
      );
    })} 
    <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

Comment: I agree thanks for pointing this. But my question is is it ok/sustainable to make wrappers for both for my use case. Basically I am asking for code review and approve from experienced developers :)

Comment: @1110 Ok, I don't see any significant issues with the implementation.